# Unwanted Modal Closure After Image Deletion - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

The problem occurs when I delete an image by clicking on the trash can icon. The deletion itself works as expected, but the modal closes immediately after confirmation. I want the modal to stay open after the deletion.

I've checked the **`openModal`** function, the **`closeModal`** function, and the **`deleteWorks`** function. Despite my efforts, the modal continues to close unexpectedly after image deletion.

Any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the modal from closing after image deletion would be highly appreciated. I've thoroughly reviewed the relevant functions and couldn't identify the root cause. Thank you!

```
// Function to render mini works in the admin mode
function renderMiniWorks(category) {
    // ... (your existing code)

    works.forEach((work) => {
        // ... (your existing code)

        trashCan.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            // Display a confirmation dialog
            const shouldDelete = confirm("Voulez-vous supprimer cet élément ?");
            
            if (shouldDelete) {
                const id = work.id;
                event.stopPropagation();
                console.log(id);
                deleteWorks(id);
                // Introduce a delay to observe console error
                setTimeout(() => {
                    deleteWorks(id);
                }, 2000); 
            }
        });

        const deleteWorks = async function (id) {
            const elementToDelete = document.getElementById(`edit-${id}`);
            
            if (elementToDelete) {
                const response = await fetch(
                    "http://localhost:5678/api/works/" + id,
                    {
                        method: "DELETE",
                        headers: {
                            "content-type": "application/json",
                            Authorization: "Bearer " + window.sessionStorage.getItem("Token"),
                        },
                    }
                );
        
                if (response.ok) {
                    // Check if the element still exists before removing it
                    if (elementToDelete.parentNode) {
                        elementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elementToDelete);
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Une erreur s\'est produite!',
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    });
}
```